# sbuild error: Only one build is permitted

Tags: 14.04, apt, repository, packaging, sbuild

I am trying to build a package for ubuntu trusty using sbuild, but few dependencies are available in vivid repo. So, I added the vivid repo with `--extra-repository` tag with `sbuild` command. But I am getting the following error with that:

```
gbp:error: 'sbuild --extra-repository=deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ vivid main' failed: it exited with 255
```

Any idea how can I resolve this issue? I need that repo to build packages. TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start `sbuild` with double quotes for the repository:

```
sbuild --extra-repository="deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ vivid main"
```

Check if your user is in the `sbuild` group with:

```
groups
```

If not, use this command:

```
sudo usermod --append --groups sbuild $USER
```

Comment: I did that and it's working. But I am having a new error now: E: 20copyfiles: cp: cannot create regular file '/var/lib/schroot/mount/trusty-ppc64el-f5d89bdd-20c8-44fa-a03b-011037caed86/etc/resolv.conf': No such file or directory
E: trusty-ppc64el-f5d89bdd-20c8-44fa-a03b-011037caed86: Chroot setup failed: stage=setup-start
Chroot setup failed
Finished at 20150525-0043
Build needed 00:00:00, 0k disc space
gbp:error: 'sbuild --extra-repository="deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ vivid main" ' failed: it exited with 1
Looks like it's running out of space. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Please make a new question. That's an entirely different problem. It's good for your reputation to ask a new question, and the question is more attention. :)